# Is there any way for MapReduce jobs to create or drop a collection from a MongoDB secondary

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a MapReduce job I want to run only on a secondary only.  The MapReduce output will create a temp collection to store the results, and I want to read the results from this collection and then drop the collection.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run MapReduce jobs that output into a collection on a MongoDB secondary.  You can only directly insert/update data on a MongoDB primary.

However, you can have the `MapReduce` output [returned inline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#output-inline) using an `out` parameter like:

```
out: { inline: 1 }
```

Note that the inline output is limited to the [maximum document size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#limit-bson-document-size) (which is 16 megabytes as at MongoDB 2.4).

Answer (score 0):

The [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18502272/2767333) is accurate. Just mentioning additional information:

- Map-Reduce (& aggregation pipeline jobs) have to be read-only (from the database's standpoint) to be able to run on Secondaries.
- For MR, Passing the Setting the `inline` parameter for `outline` is required.

Example ([Source](https://scalegrid.io/blog/mongodb-performance-running-mongodb-map-reduce-operations-on-secondaries/)) :

```
RS-replica-0:PRIMARY> db.txns.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584a3b71cdc1cb061957289b"),
    "custid" : "cust_66",
    "txnval" : 100,
    "items" : [{"sku": sku1", "qty": 1, "pr": 100}, ...],
...
}
RS-replica-0:PRIMARY> var mapFunc = function() { emit(this.custid, this.txnval); }
RS-replica-0:PRIMARY> var reduceFunc = function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values); }
RS-replica-0:PRIMARY> db.txns.mapReduce(mapFunc, reduceFunc, {out: { inline: 1 }})
{
    "results" : [
        {
            "_id" : "cust_0",
            "value" : 72734
        },
        {
            "_id" : "cust_1",
            "value" : 67737
        },
...
    ]
    "timeMillis" : 215,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 10000,
        "emit" : 10000,
        "reduce" : 909,
        "output" : 101
    },
    "ok" : 1

}
```

- MapReduce jobs don't run on a secondary in the case of sharded clusters even when all the rules are followed ([Source](https://scalegrid.io/blog/mongodb-performance-running-mongodb-map-reduce-operations-on-secondaries/)). This is a [known bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5525), please upvote it so that MongoDB guys fix it one of these days. :)